# How to exact holiday names from Pandas USFederalHolidayCalendar?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to extract US Holiday names (e.g. "Memorial Day") using USFederalHolidayCalendar in Pandas library. The code below is just printing US holidays in the given range. I don't necessarily need to use Pandas for this purpose though if there is an easier way.

```
cal=USFederalHolidayCalendar()
y_str=datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y")
holidays = cal.holidays(start=y_str+'-01-01', end=y_str+'-12-31')

for h in holidays:
    print(h)
```

I know that "cal.rules" can return a list like below. Should I extract from this? If so, this doesn't look like a list of strings. What is the content type of list?

[Holiday: New Years Day (month=1, day=1, observance=<function nearest_workday at 0x0000012EF1B3B280>), Holiday: Martin Luther King Jr. Day (month=1, day=1, offset=<DateOffset: weekday=MO(+3)>), Holiday: Presidents Day (month=2, da

Answer (score 2):

`cal.rules` gives a list of `pandas.tseries.holiday.Holiday` objects. These objects have `.name` attributes (see [source](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/951239398789b077689371d30906cab5b9248f4e/pandas/tseries/holiday.py#L146)). So, you can do the following:

```py
from pandas.tseries.holiday import USFederalHolidayCalendar
import datetime

cal = USFederalHolidayCalendar()
holidays = cal.rules

print([holiday.name for holiday in holidays])
```

Comment: Thank you so much!